# |C Program| Is char or string better for identifying HTML tags?

Tags: html, c, string, char, tags

I'm working on some homework for my Operating Systems class and I'm having trouble with understanding how to write the necessary code for listing the purposes of each of these HTML tags. I'm not sure if I should be using **char** or **string** for this part to tell the program how to identify the purpose of each HTML tag. I'll show what the assignment is followed by the code I have so far in case anyone can point out what I might need to change in my code:

In this assignment, you will create a C program that fulfills almost all of the same requirements as the C++ program that you created in Assignment #2.

Assignment #2:

In this assignment, you will create a C++ program that prints a list of the HTML tags in an HTML file, followed by the total number of tags found. The program may assume that the input file is a properly-formatted HTML file and that an HTML tag begins and ends on the same line.

I'm not sure why my professor would ask for me to use feof() if that does not work for C.
Each tag name shall be printed in all uppercase letters and enclosed in angle brackets (without the attributes). Your program shall be able to identify at least ten different tag names of your choice. If your program detects a tag name that it doesn't recognize, it shall print *"Unknown HTML tag"* as the purpose. Your program shall assume that a tag name is never longer than 100 characters.

For help in understanding how to read and write characters in C and how to handle character strings, see the identifierDemo.c file.

Complete the definition of the **detectTags** function. In doing so, use the standard C functions **getchar()**, **feof()**, and **toupper()** to read and process the contents of the standard input file. When the function detects the start of a tag, store the characters of the tag name in an array and pass this array to the **displayPurpose** function. When the function has finished reading through the entire HTML file, have it return the number of tags detected.

Complete the definition of the **displayPurpose** function. Begin this function by printing the contents of the tag parameter. Then use the standard C function named **strncmp()** to compare the tag parameter to at least ten different tag names in an if-else control structure. If a match is found, have the function print the meaning of the tag. (Enclose this meaning in a constant C string in the function.) If no match is found, have the function print *"Unknown HTML tag"*.

Make no other changes to the preprocessor directives nor the remaining C code in this file.

Design and Implementation Constraints

Keep your implementation simple and easy to understand.
Declare all variables at the top of a block.
Use no dynamic memory allocation (e.g., **malloc()**, **calloc()**, etc.).
Do not use or create a string tokenizer. Also, do not read the HTML file line by line. Instead, read through the file character by character as shown in the identifierDemo.c program. (shown above)
Add no other functionality to the program other than what is requested in this assignment.
Follow the coding standards shown in source code examples and given in previous assignments.
EDIT: I've fixed my code, but now I realized that I need to figure out how to tell when I've reached the end of one html tag so I can move onto another.
**Here's my code that I've been working on: **

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define TRUE  1
#define FALSE 0
#define LEFT_ANGLE_BRACKET '<'
#define RIGHT_ANGLE_BRACKET '>'
#define SPACE ' '
#define MAX_LENGTH 100

// Function Prototypes
int detectTags(void);
void displayPurpose(char *tag);


// #############################################################
int main(void)
{
int tagCount;

printf("\n*** START OF HTML TAGS ***\n\n");

tagCount = detectTags();

printf("\nTOTAL NUMBER OF HTML TAGS FOUND: %d \n", tagCount);

return 0;
} // End main


// #############################################################
int detectTags(void)
{
char tag[10];
char tagElem;
int count = 0; // count of tags
do { //
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

scanf("%c", &tagElem);

tag[i] = tagElem; // add element to its place in the tag
count++; // increment count
}
} while(tagElem != '>'); 
do{
printf(&tagElem); // print tag character by character
} while(tagElem != '>'); // tag end condition
printf(">");

} // End detectTags


// #############################################################
void displayPurpose(char tag[])
{
      
      
      int choice = 0;
      if (tag == "<HTML>") {
         choice = 1;
         }
      else if (tag == "<HEAD>") {
         choice = 2;
         }
      else if (tag == "<TITLE>") {
         choice = 3;
         }
      else if (tag == "</TITLE>") {
         choice = 4;
         }
      else if (tag == "</HEAD>") {
         choice = 5;
         }
      else if (tag == "<BODY>") {
         choice = 6;
         }
      else if (tag == "<UL>") {
         choice = 7;
         }
      else if (tag == "<P>") {
         choice = 8;
         }
      else if (tag == "</UL>") {
         choice = 9;
         }
      else if (tag == "</HTML>") {
         choice = 10;
         }
      
      switch (choice) {
         case (1) :
            printf("Start of HTML file \n");
            break;
            
         case (2) :
            printf("Start of HTML header \n");
            break;
            
         case (3) :
            printf("Start of document title \n");
            break;
            
         case (4) :
            printf("End of document title \n");
            break;
            
         case (5) :
            printf("End of HTML header \n");
            break;
            
         case (6) :
            printf("Unknown HTML tag \n");
            break;
            
         case (7) :
            printf("Start of unnumbered list \n");
            break;
            
         case (8) :
            printf("Start of a new paragraph \n");
            break;
            
         case (9) :
            printf("End of unnumbered list \n");
            break;
            
         case (10) :
            printf("End of HTML file \n");
            break;
            
         default :
            printf("Unknown HTML tag \n");
            break;
            
      }
      

} // End displayPurpose
```

I think I have a fair idea on what the professor requires for this assignment, but I wanted to be sure.
Is there anything, here that I could possibly change to improve my code?

Comment: C does not have a built-in `string` data type.  So-called "C strings" are null-terminated arrays of `char`.

Comment: Beyond that, anything else you may be trying to ask is lost in the huge info dump.  Please do not ask us to figure out what the question is.  Present your question clearly, with just enough code and supporting information to accomplish that.

Comment: *"use the standard C functions getchar(), feof(), and toupper()"*. Um, no, don't ever use `feof()` in C. See [Why is `while(!feof(fp))` always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941)

Comment: @user3386109: "Um, no, don't ever use feof() in C" -- It is appropriate to use the function `feof` and `ferror` in C, in order to determine the cause of an input function failure. The point is that it should only be used **after** an input function has failed and not in order to predict whether an input functon will fail.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Sorry for implementing so much information. I'll take away what is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I fixed the code, I needed to use scanf() to read in input data, not file information, but now I'm not sure which function I should use to tell the program when one html tag has ended

Answer (score 0):

I think you have gotten confused here: C has no "string" data type. When people say string in C they actually mean a `char` array. So, unlike C++ (which has a class called `std::string`), there are `char` array pointers and `char` arrays; the only way they differ is how you call elements from them: `*(arrPtr + eleIndex)` for pointers and: `arr[eleIndex]` for arrays. C has lots of things that degrade to pointers, so the way of using pointers was made purposely.

Comment: According to [§6.5.2.1 ¶2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.1p2) of the ISO C11 standard, writing `a[b]` is identical to writing `*(a+b)`. This applies to both arrays and to pointers to (the first element of) arrays. In both notations, the array will [decay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/12149471) to a pointer. Your statement that one notation is for arrays and that one is for pointers is therefore incorrect.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel, "Your statement that one notation is for arrays and that one is for pointers is therefore incorrect," no, he is right. He *never said* that they are not *interchangeable*. He is right, but he is "wrong", just because of incompleteness. Just for reference, this is like saying E=mc2. Of course, I got your point, I, sometimes, use array as pointer and vice versa (I never wrote *(a + b), though, except for manipulating string, but not dereference it).